# Cast-order for inherited classes?

Tags: c++, oop

I've got 3 classes:

```
class Super
{
    virtual int getType() { return 1; }
}
class Special : public class Super
{
    virtual int getType() { return 2; }
}
class SpecialSpecial : public class Special
{
    virtual int getType() { return 3; }
}
```

And I've got a function which takes an `std::vector<Super*>` as argument:

```
void handleClasses( std::vector<Super*> superVector )
{
    foreach element in superVector //Pseudocode!!
    {
        if( element->getType() == 1 )
            std::cout << "Thats a SuperClass" << std::endl;
        else if( element->getType() == 2 )
            std::cout << "Thats a SpecialClass" << std::endl;
        else if( element->getType() == 3 )
            std::cout << "Thats a SpecialSpecialClass" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

There could be a User which inherits from class `Special`:

```
class ParalellSpecial : public class Special
{
    virtual int getType() { return 4; }
}
```

Now the function `handleClasses` is not able to understand the new class with type 4, but it should be able to use the next superior class (in this case it is `Special`).

How would someone implement such a thing? Is there a design pattern which allows to create an hierarchical order of classes and the next available superclass will be used as a fallback, if the current class could not be used (cause it is unknown)?

NOTE: The Type-Identifiers are just for demonstration-purposes. There surely are better methods to identify a classtype in C++ (RTTI).

Comment: Nice exercise, but what's the real problem? Why do you use if-else-if instead of just putting real code into that virtual method?

Comment: Can't you already do that?I.e. if the type is unknown you fallback to Special

Comment: @userxxx: There could be a lot of classes which are unknown. Perhaps a user inherits from `super`, then next inherits from another userclass etc... There also could be serveral `handleClasses` methods, which partly understand User-classes etc

Comment: sharptooth: The reallife example is about 2 applications which communicate via network. The one side could send `Baseclass` to the server. If a user needs extra attributes or functionality, he inherits from `Baseclass` and sends that to the server. A specialized server would understand that, but any other server should fallback to `Baseclass` (its better to support just the standard-attributes than nothing).

Comment: You could send the type of class to cast.I.e. when you send a response, along with the response you could send the type of class to cast to along with its super class. E.g. in web services, when a response is send and is a subtype, the type is send in the xml response as xsi:type="derived". May be a similar concept could be useful for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 possible answers here:

1) If you think you need to know what type an object really is, then maybe your encapsulation is wrong.  Perhaps handleClasses() should be calling a method on the object, and each class should provide a different implementation?

2) If this is one of the rare times when you really need to know the type of an object, use `dynamic_cast<>`.  That's what it's for.  E.g:

```
void handleClasses( std::vector<Super*> superVector )
{
    foreach element in superVector //Pseudocode!!
    {
        if( dynamic_cast<SpecialSpecial *>(element) != 0 )
            // SpecialSpecial or a subclass of SpecialSpecial 
            std::cout << "Thats a SpecialSpecialClass" << std::endl;
        else if( dynamic_cast<Special *>(element) != 0 )
            // Special or a subclass of Special
            std::cout << "Thats a SpecialClass" << std::endl;
        else
            // Super or a subclass of Super
            std::cout << "Thats a SuperClass" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats a nice idea, I could start with trying do `dynamic_cast` into `Super`. If that works I'll try to `dynamic_cast` into a subclass of super etc. This goes on until I found the most specialized class in my tree. Anything under that wouldn't simply fail to cast.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your actual problem. Usually, if you have special cases for every of your classes that you cannot cover using polymorphism, then inheritance is probably not a good solution to your problem.

Another idea would be to create a global type registry that knows about the relationships of the types. You could then use the registry to move through the hierarchy until you find a type that you can handle. The registry could just be a DAG with the type-ids as nodes.

Comment: I edited the original question. The above code should just help understanding the problem, it is no compilable reallife-code. Just call it Pseudocode instead of valid C++-Code if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

A first solution to get the thing moving:

The child-classes integrate the type of the superclasses into their own Type-ID.
- `Super` gets Type == 1
- `Special` gets Type == 21
- `SpecialSpecial` gets Type == 321
- `ParalellSpecial` gets Type == 421

The `handleClasses` now checks if the first digit is known (which is not the case for `ParalellSpecial`. Then it checks if the second digit is known (which is the case) and then prints the related message (or does whatever it wants to do, e.g. casting from `Super` to `Special`)

This concept has the big disadvantage that there could only be 10 classes per hierarchy-level. Also the concept of Type-Identifiers isn't optimal I think.

Think there are better solutions available.